# A supposedly obvious equation in Hörmander's The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators I

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis

To quote page 8.

> Another important example of a $C^1$ map is for two Banach spaces $U$
> and $V$ the map $f$ taking an invertible element $T \in L(U,V)$ (T is
> a continuous linear map between U  and V), to its inverse $T^{-1}$. If
> $S \in L(U,V)$ we have $(T+S)T^{-1}=id_v+ST^{-1}$ so if   $\|S\| \|T^{-1}\| \lt 1$ a right inverse of $T+S$ is given by
>
> $T^{-1}(id_v+ST^{-1})^{-1}=\sum_{0}^{\infty}T^{-1}(-ST^{-1})^k$

The infinite series in the last equation I do not understand, even though it's supposed to be obvious.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series

Comment: It's basically the geometric series formula, $1/(1-x) = \sum_j x^j$ with $x = -ST^{-1}$ and the norm condition ensuring convergence. It would suffice to assume the weaker condition $\|ST^{-1}\| < 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\|A\|<1,$ then the series $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty A^n =(I-A)^{-1},$$ with the convergence being in operator norm. This is called a *Neumann series.* In your situation, $A=-ST^{-1}.$ Then, $$\|A\|=\|-ST^{-1}\|\leq \|S\|\|T^{-1}\|<1\implies (I-ST^{-1})^{-1}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-ST^{-1})^n.$$ Thus, $$T^{-1}(I+ST^{-1})^{-1}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty T^{-1}(-ST^{-1})^n=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nS^n(T^{-1})^{n+1}.$$